# ActionResult for Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, layout, razor

I am trying to make a login form which is located in Layout itself therefor not in any View. Problem is I dont know how to write an ActionResult for the Layout.

If I put my code in lets say ActionResult Index() then it will only work on Index page. So is there something like ActionResult for Layout itself ?

Comment: No. Put your login form in a partial view that is rendered via a controller action. Then render the partial view in your layout.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

1. Create a login action to return the specific partial.

   ```
   public ActionResult Login()
   {
      if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
         return PartialView("_loggedInPartial");
      }
      else
      {
         return PartialView("_notLoggedInPartial");
      }
    }
   ```
2. Call it within your layout.cshtml like this:

   ```
   @Url.Action("Login", "Account");
   ```

**Update**

You could also retrieve the user and return it to the `_notLoggedInPartial` view to display some user credentials or a welcome message like this:

```
  ...
  else
  {
    // User retrieval code from db
    return PartialView("_notLoggedInPartial", model);
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

People generally won't prefer doing this, but still below is the simplest way to achieve

1. Create a form(html/ajax) in the layout itself with login fields.
2. Post it from there to your "login post" action.

   ```
   using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account")){
      @Html.TextBox("Username")
      @Html.TextBox("Password")
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
   }
   ```

AccoutController must contain an action with below structure.

```
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult Login(string Username, string Password)
{
  //handle appliaction logic
}
```